# Find unique number of sequence and reads

Tags: python

I have a data frame which contains multiple number sequences, i.e.:

1324123
1235324
12342212
4313423
221231;
...

these numbers met the following requirement: the number of each digit is from 1 - 4.
What I want to do is find all unique sequences and their reads. Regarding the unique sequence, two-digit differences are allowed.
For example:
12344
12344
12334
1234
123444
are considered as the same sequence and the original sequence is 1234 and the associated read is 5.

I want to accomplish this in python and only basic python packages are allowed: numpy, pandas, etc.

## EDIT

the real case is DNA sequence. For a simple DNA sequence ATGCTAGC, due to reading errors, the output of this actual sequence might be:
ATGCTAG(deleted), ATGCTAGG(altered), ATGCTAGCG(insertion), ATGCTAGC(unchanged).
These four sequences are considered the same sequence, and read is the time of appearance.

Comment: numpy and pandas aren't basic packages...

Comment: What does it mean "and the associated read is 5"?

Comment: Can you explain the rules for "two-digit differences are allowed"? add/remove/change of up to 2 digits?

Comment: @U10-Forward-ReinstateMonica yes but I mean some fancy and high-end packages are not allowed..

Comment: @theletz yes that is correct

Comment: Can you try to convert them to strings, and using regular expression? We need more information. For example, why first 4, 1234, not more or less? The example you have here `12344 12344 12334 1234 123444`, could be 1, 12, 123, 1234, are you using the shortest possible one? Can `12344` be another searching seed? If that's the case, I feel regular expression after converting to string could be a simpler and fast approach. I still don't understand what do you mean unique.

Comment: @theletz and read means how many times a sequence appears. i.e., 12312, 12332, 12333, 123, 123123, are the same sequence and the read is 5.

Comment: I am just listing a very simple example, the real case is much longer.

Comment: @theletz and there is not necessarily only one unique sequence, I want to find all the unique sequence so I think set a seed for regex search is not efficient.

Comment: @BillChen please see my edit, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is, the problem isn't defined well enough - it is underconstrained.

(I'm going to be using case-sensitive sequences of `[A-Za-z]` for examples, since using unique characters makes the reasoning easier, but the same things apply to `[1-4]` and `[ACGT]` as well; For the same reason, I'm allowing only single-character differences in the examples. When I include a number in parenthesis after a sequence, it denotes the read)

Just a few examples off the top of my head:

- For `{ABCD, ABCE}`, which one should be selected as the real sequence? By random?
- What about `{ABCD, ABCE, ABCE}`? Is random still okay?
- For `{ABCD, ABCE, ABED}`, should `ABCD(3)` be selected, since there's a single-letter difference between it and the other two, even though there's a two-letter difference between `ABCE` and `ABED`?
- For `{ABCE, ABED}`, should `ABCD(2)` be selected, since there's a single-letter difference between it and the other two, even though the sequence doesn't exist in the input itself?
- For `{ABCD, ABCZ, ABYZ}`, should `ABCZ(3)` be selected? Why not `{ABCD(2), ABYZ(2)}`?
- For `{ABCD, ABCZ, ABYZ, AXYZ}`, should `{ABCD(2), AXYZ(2)}` be selected? Why not `{ABCZ(3), ABYZ(3)}`? (Or maybe you want it to chain, so you'd get a read of 4, even though the maximum difference is already 3 letters?)

In the comments, you said:

> I am just listing a very simple example, the real case is much longer.

How long? What's the minimum length? (What's the maximum?) It's relevant information.

And finally - before I get to the meat of the problem - what are you doing this for? If it's just for learning - as a personal exercise - that's fine. But if you're actually doing some real research: For all that is good and holy, *please* research existing tools/libraries for dealing with DNA sequences and/or enlist the help of someone who is familiar with those. I'm sure there are heaps of tools available that can do better and faster, than what I'm about to present. That being said...

Let's look at this logically. If you have a big collection of strings, and you want to quickly find if it contains a specific string, you'd use a set (or a dictionary, if there's associated data). The problem, of course, is that you don't want to find only exact matches. But since the number of allowed errors is constrained and extremely small, there are some easy workarounds.

For one, you could just generate all the possible sequences with the allowable amount of error, and try to lookup each of them - but that really only makes sense if the if the strings are short and there's only one allowable error, since the amount of possible error combinations scales up really fast.

If the strings are *long* enough, and aren't expected to generally share large chunks (unless they're within the allowable error, so the strings are considered same), you can make the observation that if there's a maximum of two modifications, and you cut a string into 3 parts (it doesn't matter if there's leftovers), then one of the parts must match the corresponding part of the original string. This can be extended to insertions and deletions by generating the 3 parts for 3 different shifts of the string (and choosing/dealing with the part lengths suitably). So by generating 9 keys for each sequence, and using a dictionary, you can quickly find all sequences that are capable of matching the sequence with 2 errors. (Of course, as I said at the start, this doesn't work if a large part of unrelated strings share big chunks: If all of your strings only have differences at the beginning, and have the same end, you'll just end up with all the strings grouped together, and no closer to solving the problem) (Also: If the sequence you want to select doesn't necessarily exist in the input, like described in the 4th example, you need 5 parts with 5 shifts to guarantee a matching key, since the difference between the existing sequences can be up to 4)

An example:

```
Original sequence:
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP

Generated parts: (Divided into 3 parts (of size 4), with 3 different shifts)
[ABCD][EFGH][IJKL]MNOP
A[BCDE][FGHI][JKLM]NOP
AB[CDEF][GHIJ][KLMN]OP
```

If you now make any two modifications to the original sequence, and generate parts for it in the same manner, at least one of the parts will always match. If the sequences are all approximately the same size, the part size can just be statically set to a suitable value (there must be at least 2 characters left over after the shift, as shown here, so a string with two deletions can still generate the same keys). If not, eg. powers of two can be used, taking care to generate keys for both sides when the string length is such that matching sequences could fall into a neighbouring size bucket.

But those are in essence just examples of how you could approach coming up with solutions when presented with this kind of a problem; just random ad hoc methods. For a smarter, more general solution, you could look at eg. generalized suffix trees - they should allow you to find matching sequences with mismatches allowed very fast, though I'm not sure if that includes insertions/deletions, or how easy that would be to do.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `levenshtein` distance to measure the number of substitutions and deletions:

```
>>> import Levenshtein
>>> Levenshtein.distance( '12345', '1234' )
1
>>> Levenshtein.distance( '12345', '12354' )
2
```

Comment: Hi lenik, thank you for your answer. However, I think simply using the edit distance is not enough, we should find out all unique sequence first. For example, three sequences: 12, 1234, 12345, are the same sequence only if you use 1234 as the unique sequence.

Comment: @HaoyangMi since you did not explain the criteria for `unique sequence`, I think you should do that part yourself.